# An aggregation is affecting results in a major way

Tags: sql, oracle

I seem to be getting duplicates as a result of this query. The only analysis I want to do is the sum of calls/the total orders, and to be able to see how many support_tickets were generated from orders within an order range, up to a call_date. Very simple, but surprisingly complex to code up. Here is my attempt. I have also tried to change the below into a union, but still get wrong aggregate results.

The query:

```
SELECT marketing_code,
       count(order_code) order_code_count,
       order_date,
       sum(support_ticket_call) call_count,
       call_date
FROM 
    (select distinct marketing_code, order_code, order_date from table1) a
left join 
    (select count(call_ids) as support_ticket_Call, call_date
     FROM table2 group by call_date) b
    on b.order_ID_code = a.order_id_code
group by marketing_code, order_date, call_date
```

Please note, the call can happen at a much later date than the order. The order date is in table 1, but not in table 2; the call_date is in table 2, but not in table 1. Also, in the data, the marketing code is either AB16 or AB17.

Sample data:

```
Marketing code   order_code_count   call_count   call_date      order_date
AB16             30                 45            2016-01-01    2015-12-27
AB17             13                 17            2016-01-02    2015-12-29
AB16             24                 29            2016-01-02    2016-01-01
```

The sum of support ticket calls should be lower than the order count.

Comment: can you please post sample data or my assumption WHERE A.marketingcode IS NOT NULL

Comment: It is never null. I will post sample data now, thanks

Comment: why are your grouping by `category_name`?

Comment: @maialithar typo, my bad

Comment: Your SQL has no chance of running since you're missing all the commas in the select-list — if for no other reason.  You should have `SELECT marketing_code, COUNT(order_code) order_code_count, …`.

Comment: You say sample data, but is that for table1, or table2, or perhaps the expected result? We want all of it!

Answer (score 0):

You join your tables by `order_id_code`, but in the right part of your join you count all calls from one day. This doesn't seem right. Try something like this:

```
select
    marketing_code
    count(order_code) order_code_count
    order_date
    count(call_ids) call_count
    call_date
from
    table1 a left join table2 b on b.order_ID_code = a.order_id_code
group by
    marketing_code, order_date, call_date
```

Comment: But I need the call_date column

Comment: I'll give it a go :)